# Why are negative cube roots converting to complex numbers sometimes?

Tags: python

Python 3.6 using Jupyter Notebook, and I'm getting strange results from an equation.

```
print(-8)
print(-8**(1/3))
print(-64**(1/3))
print((-8*8))
print((-8*8)**(1/3))
```

is outputting:

```
-8
-2.0
-3.9999999999999996
-64
(2+3.464101615137754j)
```

When I run the parts of the equation individually, I'm getting the correct results.  But once I try to cube root the results of multiplication it is converted into a complex number.  What is going on under the hood here?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The indicated dupe target is about an exception - this question isn't asking about an exception.

Comment: It's not incorrect. `(2+3.464101615137754j)**3 = -64`.  It's just giving you one of the three solutions that isn't on the real number-line.  The under-the-hood question is interesting, though.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Same problem, just it looks a bit different on Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: `-8**(1/3)` looks like what you expected because it's not doing what you think it is - it's `-(8**(1/3))`, not `(-8)**(1/3)`.

Comment: ah!     -(8**(1/3)) != (-8)**(1/3).  That has helped me figure out why my results are switching around.